# Rails: set params but do not save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

What's the call to update a Rails record with new params, say, stored in a `hash` variable? This:

```
@user.update(hash)
```

Will *save* the record, and since I want to put the call in a callback I don't want to save it, just prepare it to be saved correctly in the callback.

Comment: I think at this point just about every new question on SO is a duplicate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `attributes=` to set the attributes but not save the record.

```
@user.attributes = hash
```

New attributes will be persisted in the database when the object is saved. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/attributes

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
@user.attributes = hash
```

or

```
@user.assign_attributes hash
```

Keep in mind that neither of these will return the object you're working on. If you want that, try Object#tap:

```
@user.tap { |u| u.assign_attributes hash }
```